# Prove that, if function is continuous on some interval, then it has a primitive function on that interval.

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to know proof of this statement, but i don't know how to prove it, any ideas?

Comment: Please make the body of your Question reasonably self-contained, not relying on the title alone to pose a problem.  Further include the context of why you are interested in this problem and/or what your efforts to solve it have led to.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then it is Riemann-integrable. A primitive function ($F$ satisfying $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$) is then given by
$$F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \int_a^x f(t) \,dt$$
This is basically the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part); a proof is given there as well.

Note that this doesn't always mean you can give an explicit formula for $F$ in terms of (a finite composition of) elementary functions; without using the integral like above.

Comment: I think OP is interested in a proof of first line of your answer i.e. the proof that continuity guarantees integrability.

Comment: Right, that's possible. In that case: continuity on a closed interval implies uniform continuity, from which integrability is proven. OP can check the details e.g. [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_is_Riemann_Integrable).

Answer (score 1):

If $\;f\;$ is continuous on $\;I=[a,b]\;$ then it is bounded there and attains its minimum and maximum values there, say $\;m,\;M$ respectively. Now define

$$g(x):=\int_a^xf(t)dt\;,\;\;x\in [a,b]$$

We have that for all $\;x,\,x_0\in[a,b]\;(x_0<x$ for simplicity. The other case is similar) :

$$m(x-x_0)=\int_{x_0}^x m\,dt\le\int_{x_0}^x f(t) dt=\color{red}{g(x)-g(x_0)}\le\int_{x_0}^x M\,dt=M(x-x_0)\implies$$

$$m\le\frac1{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^x f(t)\,dt\le M$$

so by the mean value theorem for the continuous function $\;f\;$ there exists $\;c_x\in[a,b]\;$ such that

$$f(c)=\frac1{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt=\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}\implies g'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(c_x)\stackrel{\text{continuity}}=f(x_0)$$

and this prove $\;g\;$ is a primitive of $\;f\;$ in that itnerval.